# Computer shut off mid-update and now i can't update my computer

Tags: apt, updates

Every time I try to update I get the following error, can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: usually this one is resolved by logging out/logging in or rebooting ... are you saying this still occurs after doing these actions?

Comment: Yes I have rebooted multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's no other package manager running (look for muon, apper, synaptic, etc.) then you may simply remove the lock file and retry:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Since you say you just rebooted, there shouldn't be a package manager running.
Just be careful, if there is a package manager running, this brute-force approach may cause serious issues.